# Windows 7 gets started automatically after installing elementary OS, I cannot see options to choose OS

Tags: release-loki, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

Windows 7 gets started automatically even after installing elementary OS. In short I am not getting an option which OS I want to run/select.... windows 7 gets started automatically and I am non technical man.... I feel that linux is still not for common man, but only for technical person?

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't have happened; I am not sure that all went ok with your installation.

(Installing and using Linux these days and especially ubuntu-based ones is easier than ever and easier than using Windows or Mac I think, but there are some settings during installation that you may have touched and changed in the wrong direction.)

If you are sure elementaryOS was installed:

- Boot from live usb
- Install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair)
- Try: Recommended repair

[image]

Please report back.

Answer (score 0):

When starting computer enter BIOS settings and find tab where you can change default boot loader to grub instead of windows boot loader. Windows boot loader does not allow booting other systems than windows. Usually you just need to move grub boot loader above windows and that's it. :)